# How to Build Basic "To-Do" list style Website

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a website that will allow me to list all of the different types of beers I have tried including name, type, location, and brief tasting notes. I have a basic login created and believe that I will have to store the information about the beer in a database as well (with a cell for each of the elements). I was wondering a) if this is how people would suggest going about doing this and b) if anyone knows of good tutorials on how to set this up. I plan on using mySQL and PHP for the database and jQuery for the visual side of things. I am relatively new at this, so I am having trouble figuring out what exactly to Google to find what I am looking for.

I plan on going about it similar to a to-do list (only each element would have multiple attributes — name, type, etc.). Any help/suggestions/direction would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Start with a tutorial on the basics of PHP and MySQL.  http://w3schools.com/php/

Comment: I wish I could upvote deceze +100.

Comment: @deceze: wow, I didn't know that.  The only reason I link to w3schools is because that's where I learned some of my basics (but please don't base my current skill level on that ;) ).  In future I will link to other resources :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you need to decide on the features you want to implement, and then work out which to do first.

For example,

1. you need a database, which has a table for your beer info. (but do you need another one for people to have a user account too?)
2. you need to create a set of functions that you can access from the web site.

   - list beers
   - add beer
   - etc.
3. How do you want the front end to work?
4. How do you want the front end to look?

Once you know exactly what you want to do, it's much easier to break down the tasks into jobs you need the application to do.

I'd also suggest you look at Ruby on Rails (especially + the Hobo addon) to get you up and running faster (instead of PHP) - if you are set on PHP, have a look at CakePHP or another similar framework, so that you don't end up re-inventing the wheel.

#### Update:

Once you get started, further more detailed problems will be faced, many you can get a quick answer from google or the documentation for the language / database etc. If something is extra tricky, post another question on StackOverflow.

As it is your question is too general for a more specific answer, but if you need any additional info, just yell.